# How to draw a curve like the picture below?

Tags: graphics3d

I am quite new to Mathematica. I would like to draw a figure like the one shown. Can anyone help me regarding this?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Cylinder[]` plus `ParametricPlot3D[]` of an arrow, which you could `Rotate[]` around.

Answer (score 1):

```
r1 = 1;
r2 = 1.5;
origin = {0, 0, 0};
cpts = Join[#, {-0.2}] & /@ CirclePoints[r2, 18];
arrows = Arrow[Tube[{origin, #}]] & /@ cpts;
Graphics3D[{
  FaceForm[Blend[{Darker@Green, GrayLevel[0.3]}]]
  , Specularity[Lighter@Lighter@Cyan]
  , Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.1}}, r1]
  , Red, Specularity[Red],
  , Arrowheads[0.03], Red, arrows
  , Text[Style[TraditionalForm[\[Psi][r]], Black, 16, 
    FontFamily -> "Symbol"], {0, 0, 0.2}]
  , Text[Style["BEC", Black, 18, "TimesNewRoman"], {0, 0, 0.06}]
  , Text[Style[TraditionalForm[\[Phi][r]], Black, 18, 
    FontFamily -> "Symbol"], {-0.8 r2, -r2, 0.1}]
  }
 , Boxed -> False
 , SphericalRegion -> True
 , ImageSize -> 600
 ]
```

[image]